# API Error Code 191 using feed dialog with display=iframe

Tags: facebook, dialog, feed

I am attempting to use the Facebook feed dialog within an IFRAME, but when viewing the webpage, it is displaying:

API Error Code: 191
API Error Description: The specified URL is not owned by the application
Error Message: redirect_uri is not owned by the application.

I have found similar posts, but still cannot find a solution after many hours of research.

Javascript code snippet to set IFRAME src:

```
        FB.Event.subscribe('auth.authResponseChange', function (response) {
            if (response.status === 'connected') {
                // the user is logged in and has authenticated your
                // app, and response.authResponse supplies
                // the user's ID, a valid access token, a signed
                // request, and the time the access token 
                // and signed request each expire
                var uid = response.authResponse.userID;
                var accessToken = response.authResponse.accessToken;

                // TODO: Handle the access token
                if (accessToken) {
                    document.getElementById('fbIframe').src = 'https:// www.facebook.com/dialog/feed? display=iframe &app_id=OMITTED_APP_ID &access_token=accessToken &redirect_uri=http://asp.mydomain.com:8240/socialshare/ &show_error=true';
                }

            } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
                // the user is logged in to Facebook, 
                // but has not authenticated your app
            } else {
                // the user isn't logged in to Facebook.
            }
        });
```

And for my application's setting on Facebook:

[BASIC]
App Domains: asp.mydomain.com
Select how your app integrates with Facebook: "Website with Facebook Login" (Site URL: http://asp.mydomain.com:8240/socialshare/)

[PERMISSIONS]
User & Friend Permissions: publish_actions
Extended Permissions: publish_stream

[ADVANCED]
Authentication: "Web"

[1] Note that in the IFRAME src, the value of redirect_uri is http:// asp.mydomain.com:8240/ socialshare/ - Could the difference in the port between asp.mydomain.com as the domain and asp.mydomain.com:8240 as the redirect_uri be the cause of the issue?  If so, asp.mydomain.com:8240 is not allowed to be set as the App Domain in Facebook settings...

[2] Note the same error occurs when developing the web page locally on localhost:59700/ socialshare/ (using Visual Studio 2010)

[3] What exactly are the minimum fields required to successfully load the feed dialog in an IFRAME?

[4] I can successfully run and post a messgage using facebook feed dialog example documented here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/

[5] For the code snippet above and body of this post, I purposefully added spaces in the URLs in order for me to post this question.

Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: are you making that call in the same URL that you provided in the Facebook app settings?

Comment: Hi Tim, yes, the page URL is http:// asp.mydomain.com:8240/socialshare/Default.aspx, but I've read in many posts that it is not desirable to include the actual page itself as the value for "Site URL" (just the base portion), so that's why I have http:// asp.mydomain.com:8240/socialshare/ as the "Site URL"

Comment: I'm not sure how well Facebook handles port numbers in the URL, or even how well it handles the directory path portion of the URL.  Are you able to try it on port 80 in the root of the domain?

Comment: @TimTisdall Unfortunately, I don't have a server readily available to me other than the one that uses a port number.  At this point I am looking at alternatives to using the Feed Dialog other than in an IFRAME.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: you could sign up for free hosting here:  http://www.000webhost.com/

Comment: you can use ngrok.com